# Java Appium - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, appium, illegalargumentexception

I am learning Appium with Java and trying to apply pageObjects by setup constructor to pass the driver to my test case. When I execute the code I get the following error, I searched online and could not find the solution. Please help me to investigate the issue. I am a kind of new in Java Programming.

```
Sep 17, 2020 3:29:25 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.utils.ProxyFactory.getEnhancedProxy(ProxyFactory.java:52)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.utils.ProxyFactory.getEnhancedProxy(ProxyFactory.java:33)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.proxyForAnElement(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:222)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.access$0(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:220)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator$1.proxyForLocator(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.decorate(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.decorate(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
    at pageObjects.HomePage.<init>(HomePage.java:18)
    at TestCases.Basics.main(Basics.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:79)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:49)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassVisitor(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73)
    ... 11 more
```

The HomePage.java Code:

```
package pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;

public class HomePage{
    //All the objects belongs to one page will be defined in a java class
    //1. Call the driver object from testcase to PageObject file

    //Concatenate driver
    public HomePage(AppiumDriver driver) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        //AppiumFieldDecorator give the ability to test across iOS and Android platforms
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath="//android.widget.TextView[@text='Preference']")
    public WebElement preferences;

}
```

The Basics.java Code:

```
package TestCases;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import pageObjects.HomePage;
import pageObjects.PreferencesPage;

public class Basics extends Base{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = Capabilities();
    /*  
     *  //xpath id className, androidUIautomator
     *  xpath Syntax
     *  //tagName[@attribute='value']
     */
    HomePage home = new HomePage(driver);
    home.preferences.click();
    //PreferencesPage preferences = new PreferencesPage(driver);
    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Preference']").click();
    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='3. Preference dependencies']").click();
    driver.findElementById("android:id/checkbox").click();
    driver.findElementByXPath("(//android.widget.RelativeLayout)[2]").click();
    driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.EditText").sendKeys("hello");
    driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.Button").get(1).click();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I resolved this problem by convert this Java project to Maven project.

Comment: Is this problem caused by compatibility of the different version? Any one has similar issues?